# Fastest way to create a JSON file containg all the file names in a directory

Tags: json

I have a directory with a huge number of large files, several hundred gigabytes. I want a JSON file containing the filenames of all said files. Some of these files are in folders. I would appreciate some help in figuring out the fastest way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tree -J > output.json
```

is one of the fastest ways to create a JSON file containing all the file names in a directory.

From [`man tree`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tree.1.html):

> **-J**
>
> Turn on JSON output. Outputs the directory tree as an JSON formatted array.